If Jesus is GOD! Why does he call the Father his God and why is he sitting at the right hand of God?
Why is Jesus sitting at "God’s right hand" not "the Father's right hand"? Does not help with my question. I am not trying to debunk the trinity doctrine nor am I looking for a trinitarian debate. I want answers focused on my question for a better understanding. "If Jesus is GOD! Why does he call the Father his God and why is he sitting at the right hand of God?" I'll share Scripture and leave the table open.
About three in the afternoon Jesus cried out with a loud voice, “Elí, Elí, lemá sabachtháni?” that is, “My God, My God, why have You forsaken Me?”
“Don’t cling to Me,” Jesus told her, “for I have not yet ascended to the Father. But go to My brothers and tell them that I am ascending to My Father and your Father—to My God and your God.”
Then there are multiple Bible verses that mention Jesus sitting or standing at the right hand of God, including:
Acts 7:55 "But he, full of the Holy Spirit, gazed into heaven and saw the glory of God, and Jesus standing at the right hand of God"   
Ephesians 1:20–23 "[God] raised [Christ] from the dead and seated him at his right hand in the heavenly places"   
Hebrews 1:3-4 "After making purification for sins, he [Jesus] sat down at the right hand of the Majesty on high"   
Hebrews 12:1-2 "Jesus is seated God's right hand, accomplishing our salvation from beginning to end"   
Psalm 110:1 "The Lord says to my Lord: 'Sit at my right hand, until I make your enemies your footstool'"   
Matthew 26:64 "But I tell you, in the future you will see the Son of Man seated at the right hand of Power and coming on the clouds of heaven"   

This site is "for understanding Biblical text (exegesis) using rules of interpretation (hermeneutics)." For a "theological standpoint", I would suggest asking the moderators to migrate the question to the Christianity.SE site.

This is a purely theological question.

See https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/53195/to-whom-does-jesus-refer-with-the-words-my-god/53197#53197

See also https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/59467/does-god-literally-have-a-right-hand/59490#59490

See also https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/48329/should-any-or-all-of-the-nt-appearances-of-the-designation-my-god-be-seen-as/48704#48704

@Steve  Christians on both this, and the Christianity site, have answered this question (and related ones) time and time and time again. There are hundreds of Christian answers giving explanations. This Q has now been closed, I see, for being a duplicate. Only 3 examples have been given; there are many more. This is why o.p.s need to check previous Qs to make sure that their Q is not a pointless repetition. I did not downvote or vote to be closed.

@Anne I'm not sure of your point. Of course it is a dup. and should be closed. But why are people downvoting other than for punitive reasons and discouraging such 'on-topic' discussion?

The commenters on your question are correct in that this forum focuses on biblical hermeneutics rather than theology. Thus, your question is likely to be closed. So, not wanting you to become discouraged, let me provide two things: (1) a short answer to your question and (2) a more comprehensive description of biblical hermeneutics.
(1) The Bible consistently describes God in anthropomorphic (Homo sapiens) terms, plus even barnyard terms (Gallus domesticus) as analogies that we can easily relate to. God doesn't have hands, wings, feathers, or other biological parts:

God is spirit, and those who worship him must worship in spirit and
truth. - John 4:24 ESV

Jesus is described in John 1:1-5 as the logos (word) of God (also in Revelation 19:11-16), in Hebrews 1:1-4 as the radiance of God personified, the son of God, and Jesus called himself the Son of Man many times in all of the gospels (alluding to Daniel 7:13) and in Revelation 1:13 and 14:14. Some of my brothers and sisters in India refer to Jesus as "the only begotten avatar of God."
We should conclude that God is way more complex than any human, animal, or other creation, so He describes Himself in terms that we're familiar with, both biologically and socially.
As a result, I refuse to accept any theological extrapolations concerning the nature of God and Jesus beyond what's revealed in scripture. Period. Of necessity, any such attempt will fail.
Look, if the brightest physicists have failed to comprehend quantum mechanics, the source of gravity, and the nature of existence, how much less likely is it that anyone can possibly understand the God who created and sustains our reality? Yes, this is a kal vachomer argument.
(2) Hermeneutics relies on several critical factors for interpretation. Off the top of my head, I’d include
•   Other specific scriptures – What other scriptures are relevant to the passage in question?
•   Context within the immediate scriptures – What is the subject and what are the other words being used in the passage?
•   Intellectual trajectory – What preparatory stages lead up to and what conclusions follow the passage in question?
•   Semantic range – What other writings use a specified word, how do they differ in context, and what’s the etymology of the specified word?
•   Linguistic analysis – What are the historical grammatical or idiomatic norms used?
•   Historical interpretations – what are the historical range of interpretations and references for a passage, including other major Bible translations and recently discovered manuscripts?
•   Opinions of experts – how do recognized experts and commentaries address the passage in question?
•   Archaeology – What recent archaeological discoveries impact an interpretation?
•   Logic - What logic is available to build or falsify a case for an interpretation?
Some of these factors overlap, and I’m sure I’ve forgotten some other critical factors, but I hope this helps.

"Jesus is described in John 1 as the logos". Which bit of John 1 do you refer?

Okay, I added the specific verse references to my answer.

Thx, I would question your exegesis as the logos is not Jesus until it became flesh.  When ‘it’ (1John1:1-2) became flesh, Jesus existed. It is categorically not referring to Jesus in those verses.

@Steve, John wrote that the Logos became flesh and lived among us. John also recorded that Jesus said 'Truly, truly, I say to you, before Abraham was, I am.'” Was John lying or was Jesus lying? Or maybe all you're saying is that the Logos wasn't named Jesus (actually Yeshua) until the angel of the Lord told Joseph what to name God's Son. However Hebrews 1:2,3 describes Jesus in different terms--as the agent of God in the creation and the personification of "the radiance of the glory of God." Can you appreciate why I don't want to speculate on or pretend to understand this?

To answer to your question there is only one being of God who chose to manifest Himself as three distinct persons, Father, Son and Holy Spirit. The Son eternally existed and at the appropriate time God sent forth His Son from heaven into the world in the person of Jesus Christ. (Galatians 4:4-6)
Philippians 2:5-11 explains it quite nicely. Vs5, "Have this attitude in yourselves which was also in Christ Jesus, vs6, who, although He existed in the form of God, did not regard equality with God a thing to be grasped."
Vs7, "but emptied Himself taking the form of a bond-servant, and being made in the likeness of men. Vs8, And being found in appearance as a man, He humbled Himself by becoming obedient to the point of death, even death on a cross."
In short, this means that God who always existed as God took on another form, which was the form of a man, that is Jesus Christ the Son of God. and as a Son He was not only obedient to death on a cross but He was also completely obedient to His Father. That's why He called His Father His God. Moreover, Jesus served His Father the way we are suppose to serve God, Jesus was are example.
In fact, right here at Philippians 2:3 the Apostle Paul writes, "Do nothing from selfishness or empty conceit, but with humility of mind let each of you regard one another as more important than himself." Vs4, do not merely look out for your own personal interests, but also for the interest of others."
Now, I already quoted vs5 where the Apostle Paul says, "Have this attitude in yourselves which was also in Christ Jesus." Again, Jesus is our example. Finally, "Why is Jesus sitting at the right hand of God? It's to signify His exalted position of power, authority, and honor indicating that He is equal to His Father and reigns alongside Him in heaven. Since there is only one God He chose to manifest Himself in the Bible as three distinct persons.
In fact, it's a universal law that all sons share the same nature as its father. Our nature is human being and we all have the same nature/human being but we are all distinct persons. Jesus often referred to Himself as the "Son of Man" and as the "Son of God. The one person of Jesus has two natures. One on His mother's side, human being, and one on His Father's side, deity. I hope this answers your questions.

What exactly did ‘God’ empty himself of so that he could die? We are told God is immortal, so you must be privy to more advanced truth.

@Steve Uh Steve, did you not read Philippians 2;6, "who, although He existed in the form of God. The word "although" means "in spite of the fact" that Jesus already existed in the form of God. Vs7, "but emptied Himself, (How did He empty Himself?) By taking the form of a bond-servant/man. Or to put it another way, Jesus emptied Himself of the expression of deity, not the possession of deity. Here are some explanations, https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/20240/what-does-it-mean-that-jesus-emptied-himself-in-philippians-27 I personally like what David posted as an answer.

@Nigel I cleared it up so there would be no ambiguity.

Still waiting for a suitable response to - What exactly did the immortal God empty himself of so that he could die?

@Steve, Quite honestly, I don't think you comprehend the trans-dimensional and infinite reality of the almighty God. I don't think anyone is smart enough, although many presume to do so and are most certainly wrong. But the immortal God did empty Himself according to the Word, so that the immortal God could take on a mortal human body and die for us! That assurance alone is sufficient. But anyone who presumes to understand God should first be able to explain how quantum mechanics interacts with information and the true nature of gravity and reality itself, which is far less complex than God!

@Steve Here's your suitable response! Don't your read the responses? Here are the words I wrote taken   "verbatim" from Philippians 2:7, ""but emptied Himself, (How did He empty Himself?) By taking the form of a bond-servant/man." Vs6 explains that Jesus Christ already existed in the form of God. Vs7 teaches that Jesus took on another form which was a human being. Vs8 confirms this when it clearly states, "And being found IN THE APPEARANCE AS A MAN, He humbled Himself etc. Hebrews 4:7 backs this up when it says, "In the days of His flesh," Take a guess, who was He before He became flesh?

Hebrews 1:1-4 clears it up for me. "Long ago God spoke to the fathers by the prophets at different times and in different ways. In these last days, He has spoken to us by His Son. God has appointed Him heir of all things and made the universe through Him. The Son is the radiance of God’s glory and the exact expression of His nature, sustaining all things by His powerful word. After making purification for sins,He sat down at the right hand of the Majesty on high. So He became higher in rank than the angels, just as the name He inherited is superior to theirs."
